# Concat arrays in same document and between documents

Tags: mongodb

I have the following documents in Mongo:

```
{
    "_id": ...,
    "accel": [{"x": xv1, "y": yv2}, {"x": xv2, "y": yv2}]
},
{
    "_id": ...,
    "accel": [{"x": xv3, "y": yv3}, {"x": xv4, "y": yv4}]
}
```

I would like to get the result as one singe document like:

```
{
    "x": [xv1, xv2, xv3, xv4],
    "y": [yv1, yv2, yv3, yv4]
}
```

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
       $unwind: "$accel"
    },
    {
       $group: {
         _id: null,
         x: {$push: "$accel.x"},
         y: {$push: "$accel.y"}
       }
    }
])
```

You should add a $sort stage if you care about order within the arrays.

Comment: Thanks! You forgot to use $ for group. What do you mean by order within the arrays?

Comment: sorry mb, i mean if you want it to be in order like `x1, x2 ,x3 ...` the way the query is written right now theres no guarantee of that.

Comment: I see. The sort should be put before $unwind, right?

Comment: after the group, sorting before the group will just guarantee ordering within each document. and (dont know if its possible in your data) if you got elements like `(x1,y10000)` you can only sort on one of them.

Comment: I am testing it now on a bigger database and the BufBuilder error because the document has over 64MB

Comment: i recommend adding `allowDiskUse` flag to allow its to access the space it needs for the group.

Comment: I tried, but it's the same error. I will give it a try next week as well